# want to print data on load of page automatically

Tags: jquery

this is working on click button "show" i want to it get load as the page gets load in short i don't want to click to print username it should print automatically

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myDB;
//Open Database Connection
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady()
{
    myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydb.db", location: 'default'});
}


    $("#show").click(function()
    {
        $("#user_name").html("");
        myDB.transaction(function(transaction) 
        {
            transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM phonegap', [], function (tx, results)
            {
                var len = results.rows.length, i;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
                {
                    $("#user_name").append("<p>"+results.rows.item(i).title+"</p>");
                }
            }, null);
        });
    });});



<h1 id="user_name" class="call-btn" style="color:white"><p></p></h1><button id="show">show</button>
```

Comment: write it down in document ready function .then it will written on document loaded .

Comment: it is already written id document ready function..just not pasted that part of code

Answer (score 0):

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myDB;

  //Open Database Connection
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

  function updateUsername(){
    $("#user_name").empty();
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction){
      transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM phonegap', [], function (tx, results){
        var len = results.rows.length, i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
          $("#user_name").append("<p>"+results.rows.item(i).title+"</p>");
        }
      }, null);
    })
  }

  function onDeviceReady(){
    myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydb.db", location: 'default'});
    updateUsername();
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 id="user_name" class="call-btn" style="color:white"></h1>
```

Comment: so, i think you should place it after your html element... let me edit

Comment: WHEN and WHERE is declared **myDB**?